# multipass ssh port definition on creation of vm

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, multipass

Is there a way to define the port that ssh is forwarded from guest machine? Right now it a randomly port is picked on the host machine.

Comment: Please clarify. The question is far from clear and does not say what version of Ubuntu you are using on either the host or the guest.

Comment: I do not think this is related to the host or the guest. It is related if multipass supports the functionality of defining on demand the port or you just have to do it for example through Virtualbox.
In any case the host machine is OSX Big Sur 11.5.1 and guest is Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Then it is a question for the multipass people and not Ubuntu at all. https://multipass.run/

Comment: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/supporting-users/20

I am not sure how this works but they redirect users here.

Comment: Then someone needs to straighten out whom ever is in charge of that channel.